# Inserting boolean into Cassandra using the Nodejs driver does not work

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-node-driver

I have set up a Cassandra 2.2 cluster of 3 nodes with replication factor of 2 and created a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE store (
    c_email text,
    store_url text,
    enabled boolean
    PRIMARY KEY (c_email, store_url)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (store_url ASC)
```

I am using the 2.2 [Datastax's Nodejs driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) to insert data in the table. And edit the data like this:

```
var query = 'INSERT INTO store (c_email, store_url, enabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
var params = [storeInfo.email, storeInfo.store_url, storeInfo.enabled];

query.execute(query, params, function(err, result) {
  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else
  {
     console.log("Saved");
  }
});
```

When I insert a new record everything works fine. The problem occurs when I try to change the enabled value of an existing record. The strange thing is that the enabled value is randomly changed. For example if I make 3 requests and change the enabled property to -> `true, false, true`
After the third request it may still be `false` in the database, or it may never change to false after the second request. I have no idea what is the reason for this.

Comment: You could try to share the complete code sample as there are a couple of possible explanations depending on what your code is doing. For example: the insert could fail (the above snippet ignores an error), you might have concurrent writes and the last one winning, etc).

Comment: @AlexPopescu I added the error handling in the sample code. In my code I handle the error so I don't think that this is the problem as no errors were thrown. When I debug the code only one write is send, as I test this in my dev environment and I trigger the writes manually. I tried `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` but the result is the same. Is there a way to trace the requests to Cassandra and see the prepared CQL string?